# How can I build a code that lists a string of factorials using only a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am relatively new to Java, as I am currently studying how to use for loops. How could I code a string of consecutive factorials strictly using a for loop?  For instance, I want to code up to 5 factorials in one single string- my issue is that my code only prints out 1 factorial.

Input:

```
    int b = 1;
    int a = 1;
    for(int c = 1; c <= b; c++)
    {
        a = a * c;
    }
    System.out.print(a);
}
```

Expected output: 1 2 6 24 120

Comment: If you want to print multiple times, then why is your print statement outside the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print factorials from 1 to n no. , then it’s obvious that you would need to iterate each of those no. and then for each of those no. you could call a separate function which will calculate its factorial. This way the code will be simpler and modular.

here n= 5

```
void findFactorials(int n){
     for(int i=1;i<=n:i++) {
          System.out.println(findFactorialOfI(i)+” “)
     }
}
int findFactorialOfI(int x){
     int fact=1;
     for(int i=x:i>=1;i—){
         fact=fact*i:
     }
     return fact;
}
```

and if you need to store result into a string then instead of directly printing it over there use, String Builder like below and keep appendin an empty space which will convert a returned integer to a string plus will introduce a space between each factorial result.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=1;i<=n:i++) {
    sb.append(findFactorialOfI(i)+” “);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Another solution -

Since we are printing factorials of consecutive numbers from 1 to n. This could be done in a single for loop.

```
void findFactorial(int n){
    int fact=1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(1+" ");
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
       fact=fact*i;
       sb.append(fact+" ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the print statement inside the for loop.

```
int b = 5;
int a = 1;
for (int c = 1; c <= b; c++) {
    a = a * c;
    System.out.print(a + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print each factorial as it is calculated, move the print statement inside the loop:

```java
for(int c = 1; c <= b; c++) {
    a = a * c;
    System.out.print(a);
}
```

To print it all together at the end, accumulate the result and print it at the end:

```java
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int c = 1; c <= b; c++) {
    a = a * c;
    result.append(" ");
    result.append(a);
}
System.out.println(result.toString().trim());
```